# Loading dynamic php&mysql pages without refreshing - AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, refresh

For the last few days I am wandering arround the web for a script which would have the elementss I wish for.. The best thusfar is this one http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp, but there are a lot problems, where i need better solution:

- I want no hashtags: I want all links for loading pages like folder (www.site.com/first/site/). This works magicaly on github (click here https://github.com/spjoe/deluge-yarss-plugin, and click on a random file and go back while watching adress bar). If someone knew what or how are they doing it would be really cool.
- I need dynamic content: The script above only loads "cases" from switch function, while I need the php to check the url and find a file in mysql database and echo out content from desired tables based on the url, if it is found in the db ofcourse (if I point a link to site.com/harvey the php should find Harvey in the db and display for example his phone, adress and other details, while this must not be preloaded but requested only on click due to bandwight issues).
- History: I would like to have an option where back and forward movements on the site would work flawlessly and with the animation as it works while clicking links..
- Working links inside changable div: Because there is a problem with some scripts which don't change content where the link is inside it (for example first content box includes navigation, which should be replaced with different navigation in the second box), again this work very well with github..

I hope you give me some links or even more help with some code..

Comment: Better to write a specific question for a specific problem you had.

Answer (score 1):

I think the script you are looking for is [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/), it has exactly all the features you want. You can find it on github: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/tree/heroku

**EDIT**

You can use it with any server-side language you like. For example,

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('nav a').pjax('#content')
    })
</script>
```

in your website's head,

```
<nav>
  <a href="otherContent1.php" >click me for other content</a>
  <a href="otherContent2.php" >click me for even more additional content</a>
</nav>
<section id="content">
  <h1>Original Content</h2>
  <p>
    this will be replaced by pjax with the content's of <a href="otherContent1.php">otherContent1.php</a> or <a href="otherContent2.php">otherContent2.php</a> 
  </p>
</section>
```

in your main template and modify your php code so that it looks for the `HTTP_X_PJAX` header. If it's present (see [`xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', 'true')`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/heroku/jquery.pjax.js#L295)) render only the part that should replace the contents of `<section id="content">`, else render the whole page. Pjax is then intelligent enough that if it works, it will replace only the contents of `<section id="content">`, and if it doesn't work, you still have regular links working. pjax will even take care of google analytics, if you're using it, so your tracking is still working.

**EDIT2: Example**

Ok, here you have a sample php page. be aware that I did **not** test this, i just wrote it quick and dirty here on stack overflow to show how you *could* solve this. This  code is **untested** and certainly **not production ready**. But as an example, you could do something like this (the file should be named index.php):

```
<?php
$render_template=true;
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"])
{
    $render_template=false;
}
?>

<?php
if ($render_template) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Testing Pjax</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

        <script src="jquery.pjax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
              $('nav a').pjax('#content')
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Date in template: <?php echo $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); ?>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.php?content=1" >click me for other content</a>
            <a href="index.php?content=2" >click me for even more additional content</a>
        </nav>
        <section id="content">
<?php 
}
?>
<?php
if ($_Get["content"]==1) 
{
?>

            <h1>Content=1</h1>
            Date in content: <?php echo $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); ?>
            <p>
                this will be replaced by pjax with the content's of <a href="index.php?content=1">index.php?content=1</a> or <a href="index.php?content=2">index.php?content=2</a> 
            </p>
<?php 
} else {
?>
            <h1>Content 2=2</h1>
            Date in content: <?php echo $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); ?>
            <p>
                this will be replaced by pjax with the content's of <a href="index.php?content=1">index.php?content=1</a> or <a href="index.php?content=2">index.php?content=2</a> 
            </p>
<?php 
}
?>
<?php
if ($render_template) {
?>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: it is a great script, even though there are some issues with IE compatibility,.. However, what I don't like about pjax is that its based on Ruby, and I would like to have something in PHP..

Comment: That's not correct, it's a javascript that's completely independent of the server-side language. I updated the answer with some additional info, so you can see how to make it work.

Comment: Hello!
I think it's best if you mark this answer as accepted, as it solves your issue, and just make a new one with your question about animations (maybe linking to this question), since then you'll get more and more valuable answers.

Comment: I would like to ask how can I add code to look for http_X_pjax header because the script doesn't work without that.. i was testing it with time in the header and it changes when only the content should update..

Comment: I added a **sample** index.php. I didn't test if it works, but just to shouw you how this could be done in principle. clearly you have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: It doesn't work.. The content doesn't even change, let alone without changing time (pjax on).. I also tried with:

`$reqHeaders = apache_request_headers();
if (isset($reqHeaders['X-PJAX']))´

and it doesn't work.. however i have a content for each new content in different files, page1.php, page2.php,..

Comment: Having content in different files is no problem, that's how it's supposed to work. I'll try to create a small working example this evening, at the moment I'm not at my computer.

Comment: sorry, I haven't had much time this last days. Today or tomorrow I'll tackle this. Just to be sure, what browser are you using?

Comment: have yout got some luck with it

Comment: I can't get this working either on wamp, or on hosting account, either with server request or getallheaders..

Comment: Also tried other scripts.. I can't get anything working with php..

can someone post a basic working example of pjax implementation for php?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL to display the "Correct" url when you ajax a page request you can use [PJAX](http://pjax.heroku.com/) it changes the history with `pushState` but it doesn't work on ie6-ie9 check out [CanIUse: History](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) for compatibility issues.